# Laravel relations and how to display them

Tags: laravel

So I suppose this is just me but could somebody explain how to fetch the name which is stored in table tbl_faq_categorie which has a relation to tbl_faq?

In my Faq model I've got this:

```
public function faqCategorie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\FaqCategorie', 'Sequence');
}
```

In my FaqCategorie model I've got this:

```
public function faqNaam()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Faq', 'Seq_Categorie', 'Sequence');
}
```

And I need to display the data in show.blade.php

```
<h6>Vraag</h6>
<div>{!! $data->Vraag !!}</div>

<h6>Antwoord</h6>
<div>{!! $data->Antwoord !!}</div>

<h6>Opmerking</h6>
<div>{!! $data->Opmerking !!}</div>

<h6>Categorie</h6>
<div><Name should be inserted here></div>
```

Taken out of FaqController:

```
public function show($Sequence)
{
        $data = Faq::find($Sequence);
        return view('faq.show', array('data' => $data));
}
```

table structures:

tbl_faq: http://puu.sh/mbohD.png

tbl_faq_categorie: http://puu.sh/mbojI.png

Comment: to provide a correct answer we need to know how the $data variable is passed to the blade view

Comment: taken from FaqController: http://pastebin.com/C8s4DPkq

Comment: please edit your question and put the relevant parts of your paste in it

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comments to the question you should be able to retrive the name by using:

```
<div>{!! $data->faqCategorie->name !!}</div>
```

( Or whatever your 'name' attribute is called )

Comment: I tried that and it resulted in Trying to get property of non-object (View: /srv/ftp/resources/views/faq/show.blade.php) so I suppose that there's a mistake somewhere else.

thanks for the help so far!

Seems like a foreign key issue

Comment: But I can't figure out what the issue is.

it works if the Sequence is either 1 or 2 but anything higher and it fails

Comment: maybe there is no faq id higher than 2 ?

Comment: Problem got solved. It was a foreign key mistake I made. Thanks for the help @shock_gone_wild